# Friendly url problem

Tags: 2013

Weve setup a friendly url for the search results page however we have noticed that if a search term includes an ampersand sharepoint redirects to the "page cannot be found" page wven when the querystring is encoded.  Has anyone experienced this?  How does sharepoint redirect work?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a URL that has an ampersand in the query string?